# What purpose do sizcache and sizset serve in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery, and in inspecting the DOM of my page in IE with the Dev Toolbar I see that many elements have `sizset` and `sizcache` attributes added to the element. I don't see these in Chrome or Firefox? Also, I see that many elements on the page share the same value for these fields leading me to believe it was a global value, but a few do have different values?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" sizcache="66" sizset="0">
    <head>...</head>
    <body sizcache="66" sizset="0">
         <div class="ui-datepicker-group ui-datepicker-group-first" sizcache="18" sizset="0">
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why IE only shows these, and what purpose they serve?

Comment: It's from [Sizzle.](http://sizzlejs.com/) which is part of jQuery.

Comment: Interesting, any idea why you only see these in IE?

Comment: I assume you have already googled "jquery sizset"?

Answer (score 31):

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/2382a66a1ce9edf6/168046b517318240?lnk=gst&q=nodeIndex#168046b517318240

> it's meant for internal use only. The
>   jQuery core file uses it to
>   calculate nth-child. Here is the
>   source (with my emphasis):

It looks like `nodeIndex` and `sizcache` and `sizset` are all used internally to calculate the nth-child.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any idea why you only see these in IE?

Comment: Probably because other browsers pretty much support nth-child natively