# jQuery is adding a strange attribute to html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

In internet explorer 8,  emit strange jquery attributes that sometimes can cause problem and when I need to select them, the selector won't work.

I don't know if this is related to my rendering problem, but I've never noticed it before, in IE8 or any other browser. Can someone explain what these attributes are?

```
sizzle-1377765392290 ="[object Object]"
```

also it creates unique id for each element

```
i.e: jQuery110201441698622493836
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5l0r9weht23mhn/Ie8.PNG

Thanks You

Comment: which version of jquery are you using . As i can see in this http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8539 that sizzle cache bug was fixed in 1.7 version of jquery .

Comment: jquery.min.js - 1.10.2
jquery-ui.min.js - 1.10.3

Comment: well thats the problem then .Include the latest version of jquery and this problem won't persist .

Comment: Mine is 1.10.2 not 1.7 so this is the latest...

Comment: http://jquery.com/download/ here you can find the latest jquery . latest version is 1.9.
do upvote my answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here, jQuery uses it to attach event handlers etc in IE.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16341470/1371408

Answer (score -1):

As i can see in this [bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8539](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8539) that sizzle cache bug was fixed in 1.7 version of jquery .
And as per your comment you included older version of jquery 1.1.0 so updating it to latest release of jquery will solve your issue .

Answer (score -3):

You can remove this by,

```
var re = /\s*(sizset|sizcache)\d*="[^"]*"/gi;
source = source.replace(re,'');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/fMdVc/

Alternatively, jQuery has a [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method, but you'll have to apply it to specific tags:

```
jQobj.removeAttr('sizset').removeAttr('sizcache');
```

[Have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782709/what-purpose-do-sizcache-and-sizset-serve-in-jquery)

Comment: fine how can i remove all the sizzle elements when the document is loading? not by single attribute it replaces random elements.